# FindRoot::lstol error

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, warning-messages, list-manipulation

I'm getting the message:

> FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

I am also getting results and the plot that I get is acceptable, but I want to know: does the problem described in the message influence the results? Or can I continue?

```
 e1=1; e2=-1; e3=3.0625; e4=-1; e5=1; lam=632.8*10^-9; c=3*10^8; w=2*3.14*c/lam; m1=1; m2=-1; m3=1; m4=-1; m5=1; d2=60*10^-9; d4=60*10^-9; f=0.5; j=2;
        k0=w/c;
m = 0;
Wi = 150 ;                 Wf = 500;      Wstep = 10;                      

nf = (Wf - Wi)/Wstep + 1

        q3 = Sqrt[(k0^2*e3*m3) - B^2];
        q1 = Sqrt[B^2 - (k0^2*e1*m1)];
    q2 = Sqrt[B^2 - (k0^2*e2*m2)];
    q4 = Sqrt[B^2 - (k0^2*e4*m4)];
    q5 = Sqrt[B^2 - (k0^2*e5*m5)];
    wValues = Table[i, {i, Wi, Wf, Wstep}];
    R1 = (1 - (((q1*m2*k0)/(q2*m1))*f))*Exp[-q2*d2];
    R2 = (1 + (((q1*m2*k0)/(q2*m1))*f))*Exp[q2*d2];
    R3 = (1 - (((q4*m5)/(q5*m4*k0))*j))*Exp[-q4*d4];
    R4 = (1 + (((q4*m5)/(q5*m4*k0))*j))*Exp[q4*d4];
    R = q3*wValues*10^(-9);
    X = ((q2*m3)/(q3*m2))*((R2 - R1)/(R1 + R2));
    Y = ((q4*m3)/(q3*m4))*((R3 + R4)/(R4 - R3));
    disp = R - ArcTan[X] - ArcTan[Y] - m*Pi;

    n = Table[j, {j, 1, nf, 1}];
    BValues = 
     Table[FindRoot[disp[[n]], {B, 1.5578*10^7}, 
       MaxIterations -> 10^5], {n, 1, nf, 1}]
    BValues = Re[B /. BValues]
    Nvalues = BValues/k0
```

I tried changing the starting value, but the error still appears. The values that I get from programme are complex. Is it necessary for the starting value that I choose be complex?

Comment: I doubt that anybody can answer without seeing your code.

Comment: (A) Yes, the result is acceptable: `FindRoot[Evaluate@Expand[Times @@ (x - Range@20)], {x, 10}]`. (B) No, the result is wrong: `FindRoot[(x - Sqrt[2.])^2 + 1., {x, 2}]`. -- Your description of the plot makes it sound as if (A) is more likely than (B), but the constant `1.` in (B) can be made as small as ``1.*10^-7``.  Can't say for sure whether your case is OK without the code.

Comment: i added the code , can you please see it

Comment: Yes , Yes just i forget ti write it here , i will edit it but i wrote it on Mathematica

Comment: The line `dispn[B_] = disp[[n]];` throws an error but seems to be unused.  Please reduce the code to a minimal working example.  Also check whether `Length[disp]` and `nf` match: something seems off.

Comment: the Length[ disp ] and nf match yes i am sure

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

This computation fails, because there are no solutions for the parameters chosen.  An additional complication is the branch cuts that occupy much of the real axis.  Both can be demonstrated by plotting a typical `disp` expression (with `B` renormalized by `k0` for convenience).

```
ComplexPlot3D[disp[[nf/2]], {B, -4 - I, 4 + I}]
```

[image]

Incidentally, the renormalization is accomplished by redefining `q1` as

```
q1 = k0 Sqrt[B^2 - (e1*m1)];
```

and similarly for `{q2, q3, q4, q5}`.  For future reference, applying `Simplify` to `disp` simplifies these expressions considerably, especially if `3.14` is replaced by the exact expression `Pi` in the definition of `w`.

**Addendum: Solutions for modified parameters**

An alternative way to display the `disp` functions is to plot them in the region between the two branch points that occur at `1` and `7/4`.

```
Plot[disp, {B, 1, 7/4}]
```

[image]

For none of the `nf` expressions does a zero occur in the region.  However, changing some of the parameters may yield solutions.  For instance, with `m = 2`, the curves decrease in value by `2 Pi`, and those for `n >= 18` cross the axis.

```
Table[{n, FindRoot[disp[[n]], {B, 1.5578*10^7/k0}] // Values}, {n, 18, nf}]

(* {{18, {1.00403}}, {19, {1.08856}}, {20, {1.15744}}, {21, {1.21482}}, 
    {22, {1.26341}}, {23, {1.30511}}, {24, {1.34127}}, {25, {1.3729}}, 
    {26, {1.40079}}, {27, {1.42552}}, {28, {1.4476}}, {29, {1.46739}}, 
    {30, {1.48523}}, {31, {1.50137}}, {32, {1.51603}}, {33, {1.52939}}, 
    {34, {1.54161}}, {35, {1.55281}}, {36, {1.5631}}} *)
```

Varying other parameters also may yield solutions (and also may move the branch points).

At the request of the OP, here is the entire code.

```
e1 = 1; e2 = -1; e3 = 3.0625; e4 = -1; e5 = 1; lam = 632.8*10^-9; 
c = 3*10^8; w = 2*Pi*c/lam; m1 = 1; m2 = -1; m3 = 1; m4 = -1; m5 = 1; d2 = 60*10^-9; 
d4 = 60*10^-9; f = 1/2; j = 2; k0 = w/c; m = 2; Wi = 150; Wf = 500; Wstep = 10;

nf = (Wf - Wi)/Wstep + 1

q3 = k0 Sqrt[(e3*m3) - B^2];
q1 = k0 Sqrt[B^2 - (e1*m1)];
q2 = k0 Sqrt[B^2 - (e2*m2)];
q4 = k0 Sqrt[B^2 - (e4*m4)];
q5 = k0 Sqrt[B^2 - (e5*m5)];
wValues = Table[i, {i, Wi, Wf, Wstep}];
R1 = (1 - (((q1*m2*k0)/(q2*m1))*f))*Exp[-q2*d2];
R2 = (1 + (((q1*m2*k0)/(q2*m1))*f))*Exp[q2*d2];
R3 = (1 - (((q4*m5)/(q5*m4*k0))*j))*Exp[-q4*d4];
R4 = (1 + (((q4*m5)/(q5*m4*k0))*j))*Exp[q4*d4];
R = q3*wValues*10^(-9);
X = ((q2*m3)/(q3*m2))*((R2 - R1)/(R1 + R2));
Y = ((q4*m3)/(q3*m4))*((R3 + R4)/(R4 - R3));
disp = Simplify[R - ArcTan[X] - ArcTan[Y] - m*Pi];

Table[{n, FindRoot[disp[[n]], {B, 1.5578*10^7/k0}] // Values}, {n, 18, nf}]
```

Comment: Sorry, but i can not fully understand you , for the solutions of the choosen parametere B when i run the programe i got solutions ,,, and i could not fully understand how can i get rid of the problem , you mean i must just redefine q1,q2,q3,q4,q5 ??

Comment: @Aya  Although you obtained solutions, they are not correct, because `FindRoot` failed to converge.  Insert one of these spurious solutions into `disp`, and you will not get zero.  Moreover, I do not believe you can get rid of the problem except by changing your equations.  Also, redefining `q1`, etc as I did merely renormalizes `B`, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by changing my equation ,?

Comment: @Aya  It appears that the parameters in your question need to be changed to obtain solutions.  For instance, try `m = 2`.

Comment: i tried to do as you told me but the problem still as it is and i did not get the result that you wrote ... Many thanks

Comment: @Aya  Exactly what did you do and what results did you get?

Comment: i put m=2 .. and i wrote the code Table[{n, FindRoot[disp[[n]], {B, 1.5578*10^7/k0}] // Values}, {n, 18, nf}] ... But the same problem appear and the result that i got all values of B are equal to one valut that is the same of initial one

Comment: @Aya  Did you use the renormalized definitions of `q1`, etc as described in the answer above?

Comment: @Aya  By the way, I also replaced `3.14` by `Pi`, but that hardly matters.

Comment: Yes i use the normalized ... I will continue trying on it ... Many thanks

Comment: @Aya  I copied your code from the question up to the definition of `disp`, made the changes included in my answer, and again obtained the results at the end of the answer.  If you get a different result, try doing the same.

Comment: can you please write the whole code that you did in your mathematica , i will copy it and see ,, many thanks

Comment: Thank you so much , it is ok now , many many thanks